# Why [1111 1111] represents as -1 but not 255 in Integer?

Tags: c#, .net, int, sbyte

I do a number sign replacement according to the rule: invert bit by bit, and add 1, but I work with an integer data type not sbyte. How does the compiler understand that I am changing the sign,

[image]

and not returning the value 255?

```
        int operand1 = 0, operand2 = 0;
        int result;

        operand1 = 0x01;                            // [0000 0001]
        result = ~operand1;                         // [1111 1110]
        result++;                                   // [1111 1111]

        Console.WriteLine(" ~ {0} + 1 = {1} ", operand1, result);
```

output:
" ~ 1 + 1 = -1 "

Comment: Compare the bits in both byte and integer, and you will have your answer

Comment: But in what way ?

Comment: You’re saying “invert all bits”, not “invert lowest 8 bits”

Comment: Got it, so uint also can fix this "problem".

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496810/the-way-c-sharp-represents-negative-integers-in-memory-and-casts-them-unchecked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are signed and unsigned integers.  The signed integers can hold negative values and as such the "upper" portion of the range counts from (0- (int.max / 2)) and down.

See this article :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

if you use an Unsigned int, it behaves as I think you'd expect.

In signed ints the highest bit determines if its a negative value.